# Permanent residence card UK

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit, citizenship

My family and I are applying for a permanent residence card. We have been living in the UK for 6 years and I was wondering if it convenient to consider the original date when we first arrived 6 years ago or just 5 years counting back from now?
Our intention is to live in the UK and apply also for citizenship. I am a EEA citizen.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "consider"?

Answer (score 1):

If the authority asked for the original date when you first arrive in the UK, **put the actual date when you first arrive in the UK** (see note below on what they expect as "first arrival"). The people processing your application will figure out that is more than five years ago, provided you have the relevant evidence.

Putting the date of five years counting back from now for the sake of convenience would not help anyone processing your application. You risk contradicting other evidences you are providing to support your claim that you have been here for the right period, and presenting a case of deception/fraud.

This is echoed by the declaration you will be signing when you fill in the [EEA(PR)](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/723572/eea-_pr_-07-18.pdf) form (emphasis mine):

> I hereby apply for a document certifying permanent residence / permanent residence card for myself and any family members included in this application. **The information I have given in this form is complete and is true to the best of my knowledge.**
>
> [...]
>
> I am aware that **it is an offence to make a statement or representation which I know to be false
> or do not believe to be true**, or to obtain, or seek to obtain a document certifying permanent
> residence or permanent residence card by means which include deception.

---

Note: The question is not clearly worded in the EEA(PR) form, though in the [SET(O) form](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/722191/set-_o_-07-18.pdf) the Home Office elaborated the question a bit:

> 6.1 When did you (the main applicant) first enter the UK? This refers to the date you entered the UK at the beginning of the period of stay on which this application is based.

Comment: The question is somewhat poorly worded.  It asks for the "date you first entered the UK".  For someone who moved to the UK in 2013, but visited the UK in 2003, they surely don't want them to enter a date in 2003 and then report a ten-year absence.  What would the reason for the absence be, "not a UK resident"?

Comment: I did made an assumption that the arrival is the one relevant to the PR application. Though I just realise the clarification is only given on the [SET(O) form](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/722191/set-_o_-07-18.pdf) but not the EEA(PR) form - "6.1 When did you (the main applicant) first enter the UK? This refers to the date you entered the UK at the beginning of the period of stay on which this application is based." Will update answer once I find a better machine.